# .htaccess redirect all subpages to parent page

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

What I am trying to achieve is to redirect pages like this:

`http://mydomain.com/parent/child_no1`
`http://mydomain.com/parent/child_no2`
`http://mydomain.com/parent/child_no3`

No matter what comes after /parent/ I want it to redirect to /parent/index.php

I've looked into it on stackoverflow but there lots of similar topics with no answer. So I try to work on it myself.

Here is what it didn't work:

```
RewriteRule ^/parent/.*$ http://mydomain.com/parent/ [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^/parent/(.*)$ http://mydomain.com/parent/ [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^parent(/(.*))$ http://mydomain.com/parent/ [R=301,L,NC]

RedirectMatch 301 ^/parent/.*$ http://mydomain.com/parent/
```

The problem is that accessing `http://mydomain.com/parent/` also gets redirected which causes a redirection loop.

Does anyone have a solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

Try this, (Forwarding request using url-rewriting)

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^parent/(.*)$ /index.php?$1 [QSA,L]
```

**EDIT**

**ANOTHER SOLUTION TO MAKE ACTUAL REDIRECTION**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/parent/index.php$
RewriteRule ^parent/.*$ http:/parent/index.php [R=301,QSA,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

The following should work:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/parent/index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/parent/
RewriteRule ^parent/(.*)$ http://www.mydomain.com/parent [r=302,L]
```

What should redirect all pages to the `parent/` except the `parent/index.php` and `parent/`

Change the `R=302` to `R=301` when you are sure the redirect is working.

Answer (score 0):

This rule should take care of it:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^parent/(?!index\.php).+)$ /parent/index.php [L,NC]
```